# Do I have any responsibility over 3rd party data collection?

Tags: privacy

I have a little game that does not collect any user data whatsoever, nor does it resell it or anything else. I do employ Google Ads, and the game is planned to be released on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/).

I do not know what user data Google has collected, and I have absolutely no control over what they will do with it. Do I have any responsibility for it? If so, then to be honest I have no idea what they collected, and I wouldn't know how to list it even if I wanted to.

Or could I just say something like, "Third-Party Data Collection has nothing to do with me" in my Privacy Policy?

Comment: If Google’s data collection has nothing to do with you, then why is Google paying you to let them do it?

Comment: Are you located in the EU/EEA/UK? If not, then you can probably get away with not worrying about privacy at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply stating that third-party collection of data has nothing to do with you is not sufficient in your Privacy Policy. You are responsible for ensuring compliance with applicable laws and regulations related to data privacy, including providing clear and accurate disclosures about data collection and use in your [Privacy Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_policy). While you may not have direct control over the practices involved in the data collection process of third parties, you still have a responsibility to inform users about these practices and obtain their consent as necessary.

You can include a statement in your Privacy Policy about the use of third-party services like [Google Ads](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-US), and inform users that these services may collect data and that you have no control over the data collection or use practices of these third parties.